# Radicals and addition of ideals, proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

I'm going through a proof, and I've understood all of it apart from one stage. It's on the 5th line of the second paragraph, where the author says "$x^{m+n}=pq+psb+qra+rsab \in P+(ab)$" I don't understand why $x^{m+n}$ should be in $P+(ab)$. The terms $psb$ and $qra$ aren't necessarily in $P$ or $(ab)$ as far as I can tell. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I've screen captured the proof and put it on dropbox:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17606191/radicals.gif
Thanks for any replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $q \in P$ by hypothesis.  This implies that $pq + psb + qra \in P$.  Certainly $rsab \in (ab)$.  So the sum $pq + psb + qr + rsab \in P + (ab)$.  (If you want to be fancy, you can write $\mathfrak{P}$ via \mathfrak{P}.)

Comment: Oh I see, thanks! I'm not sure why I didn't see that now!